# Unable to map JSON field from postgres DB to POJO class

Tags: java, json, postgresql

I have below code in place where I am trying to get only 1 column (JSON type) from postgres DB and map it to a POJO class. But, in the result I am getting correct count but with null values only, even though data is present. Any Help/Suggestion is appreciated.

POJO Class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EmployeePayload {

    private String empName;

    private String empID;

   //getters and setters
}
```

Query Execution Code ::

```
String query = "SELECT emp_payload FROM EmpDetails";
ResultSetHandler<List<EmployeePayload>> employeePayload = new BeanListHandler<EmployeePayload>(EmployeePayload.class);
        List<EmployeePayload> resultList = runner.query(dbConnection, query, employeePayload);

        log.info(":: resultList is :: " + resultList);
```

Data in DB ::

"{""empName"":""james"",""empID"":""008""}",
"{""empName"":""bond"",""empID"":""007""}"

Result in Log ::

resultList is :: [EmployeePayload{empName='null', empID='null'}, EmployeePayload{empName='null', empID='null'}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BeanListHandler` comes from apache dbutils ([docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/index.html))

By looking at the docs / source, it's implemented by mapping single columns to single properties of the Bean. You are essentially trying to map a single column to multiple properties which does not work. Now there are two ways to go about this:

1. Writing your own `RowProcessor`
2. Rewriting the query to return multiple columns.

In this situation I would favor the second solution for it's simplicity as postgres has this functionality built-in for its json field types.

Your query could look like this:

```java
String query = "SELECT emp_payload->'empName' AS empName, emp_payload->'empID' AS empID FROM EmpDetails";
```

(The `AS ...` might not be necessary but I don't know how psql generates the column names for extracted json values).

If you would execute this query directly in postgres, you would get a result set with column names `empName` and `empID` which is exactly what the `BeanProcessor` (the default processor for `BeanListHandler`) expects.

Comment: I went with the second solution, Thanks.